# Hadoop namenode formatting windows - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, windows-10, hadoop3

I am in a databasing class at school and my professor is having us work with hadoop v3.2.1. In following a youtube tutorial to install on windows, I am stuck on the formatting namenode part. this is what comes up in cmd:

```
2020-03-15 15:38:05,819 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
2020-03-15 15:38:05,819 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2020-03-15 15:38:05,820 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 889 MB = 273.1 KB
2020-03-15 15:38:05,820 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
2020-03-15 15:38:05,883 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-381120843-10.0.0.230-1584301085876
2020-03-15 15:38:05,884 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2044)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:613)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
2020-03-15 15:38:05,887 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2020-03-15 15:38:05,889 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at DrStrange/10.0.0.230
************************************************************/
```

and here are my properties:

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop-3.2.1\data\namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>C:\hadoop-3.2.1\data\datanode</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and i was following this tutorial:
[How to Install Hadoop on Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=227&v=vLVWrGGqGJU&feature=emb_logo) until about halfway through when i realized it was too old and then switched to this one:
[How to Install Hadoop 3.2.0 in Windows10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGNfLfdyxY0)

Also, I have no idea if this is related to my current problem, so I will say this. When I skip to the next step and type start-all, resource manager and node manager both error out. Figured I'd stuff it all into one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error is a [Bug in Hadoop 3.2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-14890).

This issue will be solved within the next release. For now, you can fix it temporarily using the following steps:

1. Download `hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar` file from the [following link](https://github.com/FahaoTang/big-data/blob/master/hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar).
2. Rename the file name `hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar` to `hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.bak` in folder `%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs`
3. Copy the downloaded `hadoop-hdfs-3.2.1.jar` to folder `%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs`

### References

- [Installing Hadoop 3.2.1 Single node cluster on Windows 10](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-hadoop-3-2-1-single-node-cluster-on-windows-10-ac258dd48aef)
- [Install Hadoop 3.2.1 on Windows 10 Step by Step Guide](https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/377/latest-hadoop-321-installation-on-windows-10-step-by-step-guide)

Answer (score 1):

It is well known apparently that hadoop 3.2.1 doesn't work on windows 10 properly. I installed 3.2.0 and am now making progress.